# Name for God-Type Creature

Tags: gods, names

I don't know if you are allowed to ask names here but whatever. In my world, this god awakens and is now unleashing its wrath upon humanity for seeming no reason. This creature/god has massive effects on both the human consciousness as well as well as the world itself. Erecting huge mountains and driving anyone in the line of sight of the thing permanently insane. My question is what this creatures name, both by the people affected by it and its real name. Leave any questions about it below.

Comment: Regrettably, fishing for ideas is generally not suitable for Stack Exchange sites which are designed in a one-question/one-right answer format.  It's asking for opinions and there is generally no "right answer."  Consider, for example, that we know nothing about the culture, language, philosophy, science, or religion of the affected people.  And yet, the "right answer" must be born of all those things (and probably more).  Without substantial additional insight, this question is likely to be closed.  Can you provide that insight?

Comment: Possibly instead of asking for a name for this god, you might be able to ask the name or term that describes this type of god.